# django custom form getting __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    options = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.none(), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    def __init__(self, question_id=None):
        if question_id:
            super(QuestionForm, self).__init__()
            question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)

            self.fields['options'].queryset = Option.objects.filter(question = question)
```

In my view I am calling the form to get what was selected by the user in the post with this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, question.id)
        if form.is_valid():
            print form
```

I then get the following error:

```
__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

For this line: `form = QuestionForm(request.POST, question.id)`

Comment: Well, your form does indeed only take 2 arguments; `self` and `question_id` but your code passes in `request.POST` as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can I get it to take the POST as well so I can validate the form?

Comment: By adding another parameter in your `__init__` method, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The error is exactly what it says: Your `QuestionForm.__init__` takes only two arguments (`self` and `question_id`), but you give it three (`self` (which is always given to instance methods), `request.POST` and `question.id`. Your `__init__` method needs to take yet another argument to work, e.g.:

```
def __init__(self, method, question_id):
```

Comment: Thanks! what is the method parameter?

Comment: You use `request.POST` when calling it, so I thought that name was fitting. You can name it whatever you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, question_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now it works in all cases and not just for your particular form.